# How would you reproduce 70's style Sci fi Lighting in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

I'm wondering how I would create a rendering setup that gives the feel of the old 1970's era sci fi space scenes (Star wars, Alien etc.) I'm using Blender cycles to do this. Below I have what i'm trying to make along with an example from star wars and alien.

Alien:[image]

Star Wars:[image]

What I'm trying to reproduce:

[image]

Edit: I already have any models and textures, all I'm looking for is the lighting setup to achieve this effect. I've done holographic/wireframe stuff in cycles before and I've made space scenes with this harsh lighting in blender internal but I cant figure out how to in cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would install Filmic-Blender for the epic contrast:
https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender

Then either model my own spaceship by extruding parts of a mesh,
or randomly generate one with a script, then edit it however you like:
https://github.com/a1studmuffin/SpaceshipGenerator

You can apply a *Decimate modifier* to reduce geometry at this point,
for a quicker render, if you prefer.

Once model looks OK, duplicate it.  Use **Wireframe modifier** on the copy,
and paint that version with a mix of *Glass* and *Emission* shaders.

[image: TronGlow]

Then you get that nice sci-fi Tron glow.  Play with settings to achieve desired results.
Thickness of wireframe, turn the mix Factor to more glass, less emission...

Here's the quick settings I used just to illustrate the idea:

[image: glassy glow]

Edit:  You can put a tangent into the Emission shader *Strength input,*
to get more spaceship, less glow, as it appears in your goal.

[image: Ztan]

[image: GlowShip]

Comment: And don't forget the greebles. For those that don't know the discombobulator addon was merged into the extra objects addon which is part of the standard release.